# How to add application permissions to my own App on azure AD

Tags: azure

I have created an App Registration that exposes an API and a scope.

I then create a frontend app/client with another App Registration and I can add my own API as delegated permission and ask Azure AD for a token to the API on behalf of me using normal OAuth flows.

Let's say a 3 client needs access to the API but not as a given user but as the application itself. In the UI of Azure AD, there are no "Application Permissions" for my own API when adding this 3rd API and try to give it access to an API. What is the equivalent of this and how do I set it up?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have an older article that shows you how to do it through the manifest.

https://joonasw.net/view/defining-permissions-and-roles-in-aad

Currently there is no UI for defining app permissions, so you'll have to do it through the manifest or with PowerShell.

Essentially you need to define an appRole with an allowed member type of Application.
That is an app permission that can then be assigned to apps.
It will appear in the roles claim in the token.

```
{
  "appRoles": [
  {
    "allowedMemberTypes": [
      "Application"
    ],
    "displayName": "Read all todo items",
    "id": "f8d39977-e31e-460b-b92c-9bef51d14f98",
    "isEnabled": true,
    "description": "Allow the application to read all todo items as itself.",
    "value": "Todo.Read.All"
  }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, follow up, it seams it s not needed to do this - i could request a token to my app using client credential without having any application type roles.

Comment: Yes that is true. However, so can any other app in your tenant, including the SaaS applications. Define the permission and check for it. It's required to keep your API fully secure.

Comment: are you saying that if i define the definition given above, azure ad will verify and not give tokens? or are you saying that i should verify that the token is valid and limited to known clientids?

Comment: You should verify the token contains the app permission or a delegated permission. Azure AD allows apps to get app-only tokens for any API in the tenant where they are. If they don't have app permissions, then they won't be in the token. But the token is otherwise valid. A list of valid client ids is another alternative way of authorisation :)

Comment: ahh that makes sense- so if i make app roles then i get them in the token and can validate, and if not using that i should block unknown client ids. scarry that saas apps (if they know application id) can get a token just like that. I think many people have created app regs and scopes without knowing this.

Comment: Yes.. It's a lesser known feature :/ Thankfully only possible within tenant boundaries.